# Pandas DataFrame error with .mat file input on a PCA script

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape, pca

I'm trying to implement PCA for image compression using python, but I'm encountering issue in two of the lines

I'm using a script which involves sklearn.decomposition, sklearn.preprocessing, scipy.io, and some other basic packages. My input is a 3100 x 10944 matrix (matrix.mat). The matrix is constructed of 3100 images (each has 38 x 288 pixels) which is flattened into an array. It consists of integer between 1-255.
The matrix is converted from .csv to .mat using MATLAB.
It has no header.

The following code is courtesy of dilloncamp.com (http://dilloncamp.com/projects/pca.html).

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
import scipy.io as sio
import matplotlib.image as image
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#Image is stored in MATLAB dataset
X = sio.loadmat('matrix.mat')
X = pd.DataFrame(X['X'])
#Normalize data by subtracting mean and scaling
X_norm = normalize(X)
#Set pca to find principal components that explain 99%
#of the variation in the data
pca = PCA(.99)
#Run PCA on normalized image data
lower_dimension_data = pca.fit_transform(X_norm)
#Lower dimension data is 5000x353 instead of 5000x1024
lower_dimension_data.shape
#Project lower dimension data onto original features
approximation = pca.inverse_transform(lower_dimension_data)
#Approximation is 5000x1024
approximation.shape
#Reshape approximation and X_norm to 5000x32x32 to display images
approximation = approximation.reshape(-1,32,32)
X_norm = X_norm.reshape(-1,32,32)
for i in range(0,X_norm.shape[0]):
X_norm[i,] = X_norm[i,].T
approximation[i,] = approximation[i,].T
fig4, axarr = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(8,8))
axarr[0,0].imshow(X_norm[4999,],cmap='gray')
axarr[0,0].set_title('Original Image')
axarr[0,0].axis('off')
axarr[0,1].imshow(approximation[4999,],cmap='gray')
axarr[0,1].set_title('99% Variation')
axarr[0,1].axis('off')
```

I encounter this error:

> X = pd.DataFrame(X['X'])
>
> KeyError: 'X'

It's quite confusing because it's on the early part of the code.
When I use the website original input file, which is a input is a 5000 x 1024 matrix and also consists of integer between 1-255, it works fine. The original input is also a stack of flattened images, but they have more images, 5000, each is 32 x 32 (square).

What I understand pandas.dataframe is used to grid our input, but I'm not too sure what (X['X']) means. What does it mean?
And why for the reshape they use -1 in reshape(-1,32,32)?

Thanks

EDIT:
When I used the website matrix file, and changed all X to A, it gives me the same error. I don't uderstand at all, it seems it only works if X is named X.
Why is it like this? Is it related to sklearn.preprocessing??

EDIT2:
FOUND THE CULPRIT!
The .mat file actually contains a matlab variable with a certain name when we open it in Matlab.
The website file in matlab is named ex7faces.mat originally (you can google it and download it). If we open it in Matlab it will be opened as variable "X".
That is why changing ['X'] to ['A'] does not work!!
My own .mat file contains "M" variable in Matlab, now I can get through the key error.

Comment: confusing variable names, but after the line `X = sio.loadmat('matrix.mat')`, `X` is a python `dict`, which presumably should have a key `X`. after `.loadmat`, what is `print(X.keys())`

Comment: @ChrisA print(X.keys()) gives me: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1024, step=1)

Comment: To make things more confusing, when I use the website .mat file, there's no error. I even manually reduced my matrix file to match the website file, and it still gives me KeyError :((